# How do I create an array of objects based on array of JSON objects using SwiftyJSON (in Swift)?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

Here's the JSON I am getting from the server:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Shampoo",
            "price": 9
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Here's my `Item` class in Swift:

```
class Item {
    var name: String
    var price: Float
    init(name: String, price: Float) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

I want to create an `Item` object for each JSON object in the `items` array using SwiftyJSON. So I thought I'd just loop through the Swift array that SwiftyJSON will create for me and voila. But SwiftyJSON throws an error saying `items` is not an array. I tried subscripting it as a dictionary but you can't (I thought you could) iterate through a dictionary in a for-loop.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
let json = JSON(data: data) // data is the JSON from the server (above) and isn't nil
let items = json["items"].array // this is nil and where SwiftyJSON throws the error.
// error checking and optional unwrapping etc.
for item in items {
    var itemsList: [Item] = []
    itemsList.append(Item(name: item["name"], price: item["price"]))
}
```

I feel like this should be pretty easy so if anyone can find where I went wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Try to print `json["items"]` and see what it is?

Comment: @kennytm It looks like it's a tuple with the raw JSON as a string and array that is nil.

Comment: check if the original JSON is formatted correctly?

Comment: It's the same as what I posted so if that's correct then the JSON in my app is correct. I feel like it has something to do with top level being an object instead of an array but I don't know why that would cause a problem.

Comment: is `.arrayValue` the correct getter instead? https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @markedwardmurray I tried both; .array returns nil and .arrayValue returns an empty array. The error is the same.

Comment: Is this error a run-time error or a compiler error, and what's the exact description of it?

Comment: Neither. This is SwiftyJSON's error message: "Optional(Error Domain=SwiftyJSONErrorDomain Code=901 \"Dictionary[\"items\"] failure, It is not an dictionary\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Dictionary[\"items\"] failure, It is not an dictionary})"

Comment: This would be a run-time error, and it seems like the top level or response object could be an array instead of a dictionary: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L480 Try logging the `json` object right after initializing it with the data. There might be a response header level that you have to dig through.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), it is another JSON parser library for swift.
It support mapping an array out of the box.

Just declare your server response object like:

```
class ServerResponse: Mappable {
    var array: [Item]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        array       <- map["items"]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really cool but I can't really use it until my problem is solved because I can't access the data from SwiftyJSON because it is returning an error when I try to create an array from my JSON array.

Comment: It is an alternative to SwiftyJSON, you should use it instead

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do in my project...

```
guard let cityName = json["city"]["name"].string else {return}
guard let cityID = json["city"]["id"].int else {return}

var allForecasts = [Forecast]()
guard let allStuff = json["list"].array else {return}

      for f in allStuff {
          guard let date = f["dt"].double else {continue}
          let dateUnix = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
          guard let temp = f["main"]["temp"].double else {continue}
          guard let tempMin = f["main"]["temp_min"].double else {continue}
          guard let tempMax = f["main"]["temp_max"].double else {continue}
          guard let pressure = f["main"]["pressure"].double else {continue}
          guard let humidity = f["main"]["humidity"].double else {continue}
          guard let description = f["weather"][0]["description"].string else {continue}
          guard let icon = f["weather"][0]["icon"].string else {continue}
          guard let wind = f["wind"]["speed"].double else {continue}

     let weather = Forecast(temperature: temp, maximum: tempMax, minimum: tempMin, description: description, icon: icon, humidity: humidity, pressure: pressure, wind: wind, date: dateUnix)

     allForecasts.append(weather)
     }

let fullWeather = City(cityID: cityID, cityName: cityName, forecasts: allForecasts)
```

I think it's helpful.

Comment: Can you add the JSON that you're parsing?

Comment: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=beograd&appid=7c0f97effa6938625b48aecf94e4501c  This is link and paste it into jsonLint and you can see how json look likes.